# Tkinter .withdraw() strange behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Using the following code, the Tkinter root window will be hidden:

```
def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.iconify()
    a = open(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(), 'r')

main()
```

However, using this variation, the root window will not be hidden:

```
class Comparison:
    def __init__(self, file=open(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(),'r')):
        self.file = file
        self.length = sum(1 for _ in self.file)

def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.iconify()
    a = Comparison()

main()
```

Why does calling `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` with the constructor cause this behaviour? I have tried both `root.withdraw()` and `root.iconify()` and experienced the same behaviour.

It may be worth noting that I am on OSX 10.11.6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
def __init__(self, file=open(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(),'r')):
```

That *immediately* runs `open(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(),'r')`, because default arguments are evaluated when the function is defined. Therefore, when you run the second code block, the interpreter creates a necessary Tkinter root window and opens that file chooser while it's still defining that class. *After* that, you define a function `main`. Finally, you call `main()`, which creates a root object, withdraws it, and instantiates an object of the `Comparison` class. The root window you explicitly created with `root = Tkinter.Tk()` *is* hidden. The older one, that Python was forced to create in order for the file dialog to exist, however, was not.

To fix this, put the default behavior into the method body rather than its signature:

```
class Comparison:
    def __init__(self, file=None):
        if file is None:
            self.file = open(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(),'r')
        else:
            self.file = file
        self.length = sum(1 for _ in self.file)
```